# i cannot understand this enclosing function

Tags: python

why kubik() can be called?

```
def funtionsaufsummerier_fabrik(x):
    def funktionaufsummerier(n):
        return sum([x(i) for i in range (1, n+1)])
    return funktionaufsummerier
```

i cannot understand the function above. x = kubik or x= kubik()?
and when i run this code on python tutor,  `def funktionaufsummerier(n):` is run first. But i think, `funtionsaufsummerier_fabrik(x)` will jump straight to `return` and then return `def funktionaufsummerier(n):`

```
def kubik(i):
    return i*i*i

def quadrat(i):
    return i*i


kubiksumme = funtionsaufsummerier_fabrik(kubik)
quadratsumme = funtionsaufsummerier_fabrik(quadrat)

print(kubiksumme(4))
```

Comment: You should learn about closures, they're in many programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

`funtionsaufsummerier_fabrik` is a function that builds another function, returning that construction.  Yes, `x` is a function reference.  The inner function will call `x` on each value in the indicated range, returning the sum of those powers.

`kubiksumme` is a constructed function to sum cubes; `quadratsumme` is a constructed function to sum squares.  When you call `kubiksumme(4)`, the effect will be

```
    return sum([kubik(i) for i in range (1, 4+1)])
```

Does that clear up the functions for you?